# Point Particle Energy Momentum Tensor from Lagrangian Density

Tags: general-relativity, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, geodesics

Given the Lagrangian density of a point particle
$$\mathscr{L} = - m \int \sqrt{-g_{\alpha \beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\beta}} \delta^{(4)}(x,z) d\lambda$$

we could derive the energy momentum tensor via

$$T_{\mu \nu} = \frac{-2}{\sqrt{-g}}\frac{\delta S}{\delta g^{\mu \nu}}$$

where the action $S$ is given by

$$S = \int d^{4}x \sqrt{-g} \mathscr{L}$$

The expression for the energy momentum tensor $T_{\mu \nu}$ could be simplified to
$$T_{\mu \nu} = -2 \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial g^{\mu \nu}} + \mathscr{L}g_{\mu \nu}$$
Computing the following
$$\frac{\partial \mathscr{L}}{\partial g^{\mu \nu}} = - m \int \frac{g_{\alpha \mu}g_{\beta \nu}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\beta}}{2\sqrt{-g_{\alpha \beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\beta}}} \delta^{(4)}(x,z) d\lambda$$

We thus find that
$$T_{\mu \nu} =  m  \int \Bigg(\frac{g_{\alpha \mu}g_{\beta \nu}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\beta}}{\sqrt{-g_{\alpha \beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\beta}}}-g_{\mu \nu}\sqrt{-g_{\alpha \beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\beta}}\Bigg) \delta^{(4)}(x,z) d\lambda $$

Adopting the normalisation condition $\sqrt{-g_{\alpha \beta}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\beta}} = 1$, the integral simplifies to

$$T_{\mu \nu} =  m  \int (g_{\alpha \mu}g_{\beta \nu}\dot{z}^{\alpha}\dot{z}^{\beta}-g_{\mu \nu}) \delta^{(4)}(x,z) d\lambda $$

This expression is incorrect, there is this additional $g_{\mu \nu}$ term. Where did I go wrong?